# Switch Set Checked False

Tags: android, android-switch

I've a Switch with a listener:

```
mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
}
```

Doing:

```
mSwitch.setChecked(false);
```

has no effect, callback is not triggered.
Instead like this:

```
mSwitch.setChecked(true);
mSwitch.setChecked(false);
```

works as expected. Am I doing something wrong? If the checkbox state is false and one use setChecked(false), the normal behaviour is to skip callback? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be **Called when the checked state of a compound button has changed.**

So if its state is already false it won't be called when you call false.

Comment: Ok, I've some business logic in that callback...so I'll have to replicate.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not a bug, is the normal behavior.

If you look the code of the CompoundButton you can see

```
/**
     * <p>Changes the checked state of this button.</p>
     *
     * @param checked true to check the button, false to uncheck it
     */
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        if (mChecked != checked) {
            mChecked = checked;
            refreshDrawableState();
            notifyViewAccessibilityStateChangedIfNeeded(
                    AccessibilityEvent.CONTENT_CHANGE_TYPE_UNDEFINED);

            // Avoid infinite recursions if setChecked() is called from a listener
            if (mBroadcasting) {
                return;
            }

            mBroadcasting = true;
            if (mOnCheckedChangeListener != null) {
                mOnCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged(this, mChecked);
            }
            if (mOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener != null) {
                mOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener.onCheckedChanged(this, mChecked);
            }

            mBroadcasting = false;            
        }
}
```

Where `mChecked` is the actual value of the switch.

If you want to trigger every time simple override onClick listener like this

```
mSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Is checked? "+mSwitch.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback will be called only when you defined your listener and afterwords try to change it by setChecked(false/true)

Answer (score 0):

in kotlin

```kotlin
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    mSwitch.setChecked(false)
}
```